GEE_Cloud_Project_import folder into the script
I recently switched my Google Earth Engine account to the cloud project. I created a folder inside the "Assets" to download from the PC and put all the needed images inside this folder. After that, I faced a problem importing the folder inside my script because it was not recognized as an Image Collection. I listed it for printing the information in consol but can't convert it into the Image Collection.
var modis = ee.data.listImages('projects/ee-anastasiiakhimchenko/assets/USA_Modis_downscaled_2022');
print(modis)
var collection = ee.ImageCollection(modis)
print(collection)


You need to get the names. See Noel Gorelick answer of this question here
The asset is not public so I couldn't see if it worked on your collection
var modis = ee.data.listAssets('projects/ee-anastasiiakhimchenko/assets/USA_Modis_downscaled_2022')['assets']
                    .map(function(asset) { return asset.name })
print(modis)
var collection = ee.ImageCollection(modis)
print(collection)

